# Regex for Last Two Quotes per Line

Tags: regex

I'm using the following as part of SQL query and it got me hooked in trying to figure this out:

```
"ZENDCUST" as "End Customer ID",
"ZCENCSLS___T" as "End Customer Desc",
"ZCENCSLS__0CUST_GROUP" as "Cust Grp-EC-MD ID",
"ZCENCSLS__0CUST_GROUP___T" as "Cust Grp-EC-MD Desc",
"ZENDCUST__0CITY" as "End Customer City",
```

Is there a RegEx that can get the third & fourth double quote marks?
i.e. line 1 becomes 
`"ZENDCUST" as 'End Customer ID',`

This would be repeated across more than the 5 example rows.

I was able to use `\"(?!\sas)` but this wasn't able to omit the first quote.

https://regexr.com/40jhr

Comment: Try `"(?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*)?$)`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/pTZsvd/1

Comment: This worked. If you submit as answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tool or language that you are working with supports lookaheads in its set of regular expressions then you would be able to use a positive lookahead. You should enable `m` flag too:

```
"(?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*)?$)
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/pTZsvd/1/)

Breakdown:

```
" # Match a double quotation mark
(?= # Start of a positive lookahead
    [^"]* # Match anything but a "
    (?: # Start of a non-capturing group
        "[^"]* # Match one " and anything but a "
    )? # End of non-capturing group, optional
    $ End of line
) # End of positive lookahead
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the solution for you is not matching **3rd and 4th** double quote,
but the **last pair** of double quotes in a row (and what is between them).

The regex to find them is:

```
"([^"]+)"(?!.*")
```

Details:

- `"` - A double quote.
- `([^"]+)` - A sequence of chars other than a double quote, as a capturing group.
- `"` - The second double quote.
- `(?!.*")` - Negative lookahead for a double quote, somewhere further
  in the current row. This guarantees that what has been captured before
  is the last pair of double quotes.

If you e.g. substitite each match with `'\1'`, you change the double quotes
in question into single ones.

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/a7GyGS/1